# PowerShell Pipeline or Input Argument

Tags: powershell

I could not find an answer to this question anywhere.

How can a PowerShell script written in a file (as I understand, it cannot be a function in order to allow the pipelining directly to the script) be made to accept either pipeline input **or** a file input argument? The following criteria must be met:

- either of which must be mandatory;
- pipeline input is to be processed only after receiving all input into an array;
- input argument is a file and the path must be validated;
- a second optional argument specifies an output file.

The idea is to achieve a similar behavior to standard Linux commands as in `cat file | <command> [-o out]` or `<command> -f file [-o out]`, in PowerShell being `cat file | .\script.ps1 [-OutFile out]` or `.\script.ps1 -File file [-OutFile out]`.

Comment: See Joey's answer and you will understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a script like this:

```
param([string]$Path)

if (!Path) {
  $scriptInput = $input
} else {
  $scriptInput = Get-Content $Path
}

# Do something with $scriptInput
```

Checking for either pipeline input *or* an argument is left as an exercise for you.

Comment: This seems to work, but breaks (input object cannot be bound to any parameters...) when a second, optional argument is added and the pipeline method is used. I have edited my question to reflect the need for the second argument specifying an output file.